# Strange array lookup in zsh

Tags: zsh, typeset

Looking at [this example from `pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv/blob/ee18ffac9f592d1dc93130bd7b3c86c403847ec7/bin/pyenv-virtualenv-init#L149-L152):

```
typeset -g -a precmd_functions
if [[ -z \$precmd_functions[(r)_pyenv_virtualenv_hook] ]]; then
  precmd_functions=(_pyenv_virtualenv_hook \$precmd_functions);
fi
```

`_pyenv_virtualenv_hook` is a function that is [declared earlier in the file](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv/blob/ee18ffac9f592d1dc93130bd7b3c86c403847ec7/bin/pyenv-virtualenv-init#L121-L136).

I believe this code is checking to see whether `_pyenv_virtualenv_hook` is already injected into `precmd_functions`, but I don't understand the syntax.

What is the purpose of `(r)` in the array lookup?

Comment: > What is the purpose of (r) in the array lookup?
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html#l121 says that "The (r) flag takes a pattern and substitutes the first element of the array matched". So the snippet should do what you describe: Look if the element is in the array (i.e. the lookup returns a non-zero value).

Comment: @kba That suffices as an answer; if you'd like to write that up as one I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: Sure, I'll make an answer of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Zsh Guide Chapter on Substitutions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html#l121) explains the `(r)` flag:

> The `(r)` flag takes a pattern and substitutes the first element of the array matched.

So the snippet does what you describe: Look if the element is in the array (i.e. the lookup returns a non-zero value). It is obfuscated further because the code you quote is assigned to a string to be evaluated, therefore the dollar signs are escaped (`\$`).